# What is wrong in my backpropagation? (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, backpropagation

I implemented my own backprop. algorithm based on [this explanation](https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/)  in python but the loss function does not decrease over time. I have a network with 1 hidden layer, the output of each layer is o[i] and the input of each layer is z[i]. I am really confused what is wrong in my implementation. I appreciate if someone tells my problem. Here is my forward and backprop. code:

```
z = []  # value of layer befor activation function
o = [x]  # output of layer

# forward:
for i in xrange(len(config)):
    act = activation_function_map[config[i]["act_name"]]  # you can use "act(input)"
    input_of_activation = np.array(np.squeeze(o[i])) * np.transpose(w_list[i]) + np.transpose(np.array(b_list[i]))
    z.append(np.expand_dims(input_of_activation, axis=2))
    output_of_activation = np.apply_along_axis(act, 0, np.expand_dims(input_of_activation, axis=2))
    output_of_activation = np.expand_dims(np.squeeze(output_of_activation), axis=2)
    o.append(output_of_activation)


# backward:
loss_function = loss_function_map[loss_function_name]
dE_dlastO = loss_function(o[-1], y)  # dE_dlastO is derivative of loss respect to output

dE_dw = []
dE_db = []

deltas = []
delta_last = np.transpose(dE_dlastO)
delta_last = delta_last.reshape([-1, o[-1].shape[1], 1])
deltas.append(delta_last)

for i in xrange(len(config) - 2, -1, -1):
    d_act = diff_activation_function_map[config[i]["act_name"]]
    delta_i = np.zeros(shape=(deltas[0].shape[0], np.array(w_list[i+1]).shape[1], 1))
    for j in range(0, deltas[0].shape[0]):
        temp_delta = np.array(deltas[-1][j, :, :])
        temp_z = np.array(z[i][j, :, :])
        d_act_temp = d_act(temp_z)
        temp_delta = np.multiply(np.dot(np.transpose(w_list[i + 1]), temp_delta), d_act_temp)
        delta_i[j, :, :] = temp_delta

    deltas.append(delta_i)

deltas.reverse()

for i in xrange(len(config) - 1, -1, -1):
    dE_dw_i = np.zeros(shape=(deltas[0].shape[0], np.array(w_list[i]).shape[0], np.array(w_list[i]).shape[1]))
    dE_db_i = np.zeros(shape=(deltas[0].shape[0], np.array(w_list[i]).shape[0], 1))
    for j in range(0, deltas[0].shape[0]):
        temp_delta = np.array(deltas[i][j, :, :])
        temp_o = np.array(o[i])[j, :, :]
        temp_dE_dW = np.dot(temp_delta, np.transpose(temp_o))
        dE_dw_i[j, :, :] = temp_dE_dW
        dE_db_i[j, :] = temp_delta

    dE_dw.append(np.mean(dE_dw_i, axis=0))
    dE_db.append(np.mean(dE_db_i, axis=0))

dE_dw.reverse()
dE_db.reverse()
```